# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre estos dos tipos de punteros?

Tags: c

Cual es exactamente la diferencia entre estos dos punteros si ambos están apuntando a una función.La verdad es que he visto muchos programadores usandolos pero yo sigo sin ver la diferencia.

```
int(*function)(int,int)
```

y

```
int*function(int,int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un puntero a función:

```
int(*function)(int,int)
```

Se utiliza para apuntar de forma dinámica a una función:

```
int func1(int a, int b)
{ return a + b; }

int func2(int a, int b)
{ return a * b; }

int main()
{
  int (*funcion)(int,int) = func1;
  printf("%d\n",funcion(2,4)); // Imprime 6 (2 + 4)

  funcion = func2;
  printf("%d\n",funcion(2,4)); // Imprime 8 (2 * 4)
}
```

Y esto otro es una función que devuelve un puntero de tipo `int`:

```
int* function(int,int)
```

Como por ejemplo:

```
int* funcion(int a, int b)
{
  static int total= 0;
  total= a + b;
  return &total;
}

int main()
{
  int* resultado = funcion(1,2);
  printf("%d\n",*resultado); // Imprime 3
  funcion(2,4);
  printf("%d\n",*resultado); // Imprime 6
}
```

El segundo resultado se explica porque `resultado` apunta a la variable interna de la función, `total`. Al ser esta variable estática cada vez que se llama a la función se modificará el valor almacenado en la misma.

Los paréntesis son muy importantes en C, así que hay que ponerlos con sumo cuidado si no quieres que el programa empiece a hacer cosas raras.

Answer (score 2):

El primero `int(*function)(int,int)` es un puntero a función. Los paréntesis `()` tienen prioridad. Te recomiendo ver la prioridad de operadores en C, aquí te dejo un link http://maxus.fis.usal.es/fichas_c.web/03xx_pags/0303.html

El segundo es una función que devuelve un puntero a `int`

Comment: es decir en la segunda función ¿el valor de retorno es un puntero?

Comment: Correcto, un puntero a int

Comment: Te pondria algun ejemplo pero solo con buscar punteros a funciones y devolver punteros en google tienes muchos ejemplos en c, espero haberte ayudado

Comment: perfecto Edu, yo creo que mi ya me he aclarado la duda

Comment: El primero es la definición de una variable cuyo contenido es un puntero a función, el segundo es la predeclaración de una función si se agrega `;` al final de la sentencia, de otra forma, no compila a menos que se agreguen las llaves.

Comment: Por favor, edita la respuesta y añade signos de puntuación (comas, puntos, acentos...) gracias