# Cómo dar valor a un parámetro float(*func)(float)

Tags: c++, c, punteros

Se supone que lo siguiente es un codigo para integrar donde el usuario pone la funcion pero no sé cómo darle el valor a `float(*func)(float)`. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
#define FUNC(x) ((*func)(x))
float trapzd(float(*func)(float), float a, float b, int n)
{
  float x, tnm, sum, del;
  static float s;
  int it, j;

  if (n == 1) {
    return (s = 0.5*(b - a)*(FUNC(a) + FUNC(b)));
  }
  else {
   for (it, j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) it <<= 1;
  tnm = it;
  del = (b - a) / tnm;
  x = a + 0.5*del;
  for (sum = 0.0, j = 1; j <= it; j++, x += del) sum += FUNC(x);
  s = 0.5*(s*(b - a)*sum / tnm);
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Es un *puntero a función*, más información: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161948/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-estos-dos-tipos-de-punteros

Answer (score 2):

`float(*func)(float)` representa un puntero a función. En este caso la función va a aceptar un único parámetro de tipo `float` y, además, retorna un `float`. Si usamos `typedef` podemos obtener una representación más legible:

```
typedef float(*)(float) funcPtr;

float trapzd(funcPtr func, float a, float b, int n);
```

Así pues, estamos declarando un puntero a función que debe aceptar un `float` y devolver otro `float`, luego el prototipo de la función debe ser el siguiente:

```
float funcion(float);
```

Cualquier función que cumpla con esta interfaz podrá ser apuntada por el mencionado puntero. [@IvánRodríguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172059/463) ya ha puesto un ejemplo bastante representativo, luego no veo necesidad de poner otro similar.

Answer (score 2):

En C++ existe una norma que es útil a la vez que (en ocasiones) molesta. Ciertos tipos de datos *decaen* automáticamente a puntero. Éstos tipos de datos son las formaciones<sup>1</sup> y las funciones.

#### Resumen.

Para dar valor a un parámetro o función de tipo `float(*func)(float)`, tan sólo asigna una función que devuelva y reciba un `float` a dicho parámetro o función. El nombre de la función es lo mismo que un puntero a dicha función, así de sencillo.

Para más información, sigue leyendo.

#### Decaimiento a puntero.

Que un tipo determinado decaiga a puntero significa que el nombre de una instancia de ese tipo será tratado como puntero al tipo sin pedir explícitamente una conversión de tipos, eso pasa con los punteros a función (y las formaciones).

Así pues, si tenemos una función que devuelve y recibe un dato de tipo `float`, su tipo de datos sería `float(float)` con este tipo de datos podemos almacenar funciones que sigan dicha firma:

```
float funcion1(float) {}
float funcion2(float) {}
void funcion3() {}

float(*p1)(float) = funcion1; // Correcto
float(*p2)(float) = funcion2; // Correcto
float(*p3)(float) = funcion3; // Error, no coincide la firma
```

Si te fijas, no ha sido necesario usar el operador de dirección (operador et `&`) para guardar en un puntero a función las funciones `funcion1` y `funcion2`; esto se debe a que el nombre de la función decae a puntero, pero funcionaría igualmente añadiendo el operador et:

```
float funcion1(float) {}
float funcion2(float) {}
void funcion3() {}

float(*p1)(float) = &funcion1; // Correcto
float(*p2)(float) = &funcion2; // Correcto
float(*p3)(float) = &funcion3; // Error, no coincide la firma
```

#### Sólo puedes tener punteros.

La sintaxis de puntero a función es bastante confusa, por lo que se suele aconsejar usar alias de tipos para simplificala:

```
float funcion1(float) {}
float funcion2(float) {}
void funcion3() {}

using ff = float(float);

ff *p1 = funcion1;  // Correcto
ff *p2 = &funcion2; // Correcto
ff *p3 = funcion3;  // Error, no coincide la firma
```

Fíjate que hemos añadido el puntero **después** del alias de tipo; el alias nos dice *soy una función que devuelve y recibe un dato de tipo `float`*, mientras que `p1`, `p2` y `p3` son punteros a el tipo de datos del alias ¿es posible tener una instancia de función que devuelve y recibe un dato de tipo `float` o sólo podemos usar punteros? La respuesta correcta es lo segundo:

```
float funcion1(float) {}
float funcion2(float) {}
void funcion3() {}

using ff = float(float);

ff f1 = funcion1; // Error, tiene que ser puntero
ff f2 = funcion2; // Error, tiene que ser puntero
ff f3 = funcion3; // Error, tiene que ser puntero (y no coincide la firma)
```

#### Funciona con funciones miembro, si son estáticas.

Estos punteros a función pueden apuntar a funciones miembro de objetos, siempre y cuando estas funciones sean estáticas.

```
float funcion1(float) {}
struct S
{
    static float funcion2(float) {}
    float funcion3(float) {}
};

using ff = float(float);

ff *p1 = &funcion1;   // Correcto
ff *p2 = S::funcion2; // Correcto
ff *p3 = S::funcion3; // Error, debería ser función miembro estática
```

Si la función miembro no es estática, lo que necesitas es otro tipo de puntero a función, en el ejemplo anterior sería de tipo `float(S::)(float)`, que es *una función perteneciente a `S` que devuelve y recibe un dato de tipo `float`*:

```
float funcion1(float) {}
struct S
{
    static float funcion2(float) {}
    float funcion3(float) {}
};

using ff = float(float);
using pfSf = float(S::*)(float);
using fSf = float(S::)(float); // Error, debe ser puntero

ff *p1 = &funcion1;     // Correcto
ff *p2 = S::funcion2;   // Correcto
pfSf p3 = &S::funcion3; // Correcto
```

Las funciones miembro no estáticas no decaen a puntero (y no se puede hacer un alias que no sea puntero).

---

1. También conocidas como "arreglos", o en inglés "arrays".

Answer (score 1):

Te lo voy a poner de forma simple eliminando todo él código que no  tiene ver con tu pregunta.

```
//la función debe de ser **static** (una única referencia)
float func_test(float x)
{
  return x;
}

//esta es tu función
float trapzd(float(*func)(float))
{
  //Y el valor se lo das como cualquier otra función
  float x = func(10);
  float y = (func)(10);
  return x+y;
}

// para usar "func" como parametros debes usar **&**  
//dado que es un puntero a una función debes darle la direccion de la memoria a esa función.

int main()
{
   printf("%f", trapzd(&func_test) );
   return 0;
}
```

Por cierto el uso del macro

```
#define FUNC(x) ((*func)(x))
```

No lo veo necesario, puedes prescindir de él. Aunque si insistes en usarlo en ese contexto yo lo haria así.

```
#define FUNC(x) (func)(x)
```

o así

```
#define FUNC(x) func(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es un puntero a función. Al igual que las variables, las funciones también tienen una dirección de memoria, que podemos usar para cosas como la que especificas en tu pregunta. Vamos paso a paso:

#### 1. ¿Qué es eso?

Como bien has visto, la función trapz

```
float trapzd(float(*func)(float), float a, float b, int n)
{
   //...
}
```

recibe como primer parámetro una variable de tipo puntero a función. De forma más técnica, el tipo de la variable es `float(*)(float)`. Esto es el tipo de un puntero a una función, y esa función recibe como parámetro un float y devuelve un float.

Al igual que podemos tener punteros a int `int*`, podemos tener punteros a una función que reciba como parámetro un int y devuelva un char `char(*)(int)`.

#### 2. ¿Cómo los consigo?

Si para cualquier variable usamos el caracter `&` para conseguir su dirección de memoria, para una función sólo necesitamos usar su nombre(literalmente). Veamos un ejemplo:

```
int hola= 13;

float miFuncion(float x){
    return x*x;
}

int main(){

    //Declaramos un puntero a int que apunte a la variable hola
    int * ptrHola= &hola;

    //Usamos el puntero a int
    printf("Mi variable contiene un %d",*ptrHola);
    
    //Declaramos un puntero a funcion que apunte a la funcion miFuncion
    float(*ptrMiFuncion)(float)= miFuncion;

    //Ahora podemos usar ptrMiFuncion como una funcion cualquiera
    printf("Mi funcion devuelve %f",ptrMiFuncion(5));

}
```

Salida:
`Mi variable contiene un 13`
`Mi puntero a funcion devuelve 25`

#### 3. ¿Como puede usarse?

Usar un puntero a función tiene la ventaja de que puede usarse para pasar funciones como parámetros (como hace trapz), retornar funciones

```
float funcionRet(int hola){
    return hola*1.5;
}

//Funcion que retorna un puntero a una funcion que recibe como parámetro un int y retorna un float
float(*)(int) miFuncion(){
    return funcionRet;
}
```

, o tener un array de funciones

```
int miFuncion1(){
    return 4;
}

int miFuncion2(){
    return 8;
}

//Array de 2 punteros a funciones que retornan int y no reciben parametros.
int(*ptrFuncion[2])();

int main(){
    ptrFuncion[0]= miFuncion1;
    ptrFuncion[1]= miFuncion2;

    printf("F1=%d F2=%d",ptrFuncion[0](),ptrFuncion[1]());
}
```

Salida: `F1=4 F2=8`